# Having trouble doing my code

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, nested-lists

I don't get my expected output.

Let

```
lista_preguntasyrespuestas = ((("1+1"),("2")),(("2+2"),("4")))

for i in lista_preguntasyrespuestas:
    for j in range(len(lista_preguntasyrespuestas)):
        print("Pregunta {}: {}".format(j+1, i[0]))
```

and the output is

```
Pregunta 1: 1+1
Pregunta 2: 1+1
Pregunta 1: 2+2
Pregunta 2: 2+2
```

so it gives me my expected output repeated.

It should be

```
Pregunta 1: 1+1
Pregunta 2: 2+2
```

Help, please!

Answer (score 0):

```
lista_preguntasyrespuestas = ((("1+1"),("2")),(("2+2"),("4")))
for elem in lista_preguntasyrespuestas:
    print('Pregunta'+elem[0][0]+':'+'='.join(elem))
```

I saw my error. Here is updated code :). It's nice and short

Comment: Thank you so much and ROFL, why didn't I thought about that. :) sigh

Comment: Hey, I just realized that it's ok but it doesn't goes from "Pregunta 1" to "Pregunta 2" in the next line

Answer (score 0):

You can use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this example:

```
lista_preguntasyrespuestas = ((("1+1"),("2")),(("2+2"),("4")))
# The enumeration begins from 1
for k, v in enumerate(lista_preguntasyrespuestas, 1):
    print("Pregunta {}: {}".format(k, v[0]))
```

Output:

```
Pregunta 1: 1+1
Pregunta 2: 2+2
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to ask if you're not familiar with `enumerate` it will save you time and let your code be more pythonic and easy to maintain.

Comment: enumerate is very helpful for this code, Thanks once again for the info provided.